# How to extract the value from a json object in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have my ADF pipeline, Where my final output from set variable activity is something like this `{name:test, value:1234}`,

The input coming to this variable is

```
{
    "variableName": "test",
    "value": "test:1234"
}
```

The expression provided in Set variable Item column is `@item().ColumnName`. And the ColumnName in my JSon file is something like this `"ColumnName":"test:1234"`

How can I change it so that I get only **1234**. I am only interested in the value coming here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to split the value by colon which you can do using Azure Data Factory (ADF) [expressions and functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions): the `split` function, which splits a string into an array and the `last` function to get the last item from the array.  This works quite neatly in this case:

```
@last(split(variables('varWorking'), ':'))
```

Sample results:

[image]

Change the variable name to suit your case.  You can also use string methods like `lastIndexOf` to locate the colon, and grab the rest of the string from there.  A sample expression would be something like this:

```
@substring(variables('varWorking'),add(indexof(variables('varWorking'), ':'),1),4)
```

It's a bit more complicated but may work for you, depending on the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are using it inside of an iterator since you got `item` but however, I tried with a simple `json` lookup value

```
@last(split(activity('Lookup').output.value[0].ColumnName,':'))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just find out below function work for me in ADF.

```
@json(string(item())).value
```