# Change lookup object output to integer in Azure data factory

Tags: types, azure-data-factory

Hei,

I have a lookup that has a number as output PeriodeID_var. I want to use it as a variable in a stored procedure called by a Copy activity. I get the following error:

The variable 'PeriodeID_var' of type 'String' cannot be initialized or updated with value of type 'Object'. The variable 'PeriodeID_var' only supports values of types 'String'.

Is is possible to change the type from object to string? And if so, how?

I have tried int but it didn't work.

[image: This is my pipeline]

Comment: Can you please provide the expression that you have used within the Set variable activity? It seems to be pbl and we need to add additional granularity in that expression

Comment: Thanks for helping. It works. Where can I read more about it to understand the syntax?

Comment: Glad it helped. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70438078/how-to-extract-the-value-from-a-json-object-in-azure-data-factory this can act as a reference for you but the error message usually contains the details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below expression in set variable activity:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.VarPeriodId
```